# node.js convert nested json string to nested json array

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i am writing APIs with  NODE.js MYSQL  for REACT-NATIVE app, 
I am using two table posts[user_id, post_id, description, created_date] and files[post_id, saved_name], I am join this two table and group the saved_name column as file_Name,

But i had a problem with the mysql query result it comes in json string format but i want it in JSON ARRAY format ,once check the put puts

```````````````````````````````
#Current Out PUT  
    {
        "status": 200,
        "error": null,
        "res_posts": [{
            "post_id": 3,
            "user_id": 1,
            "description": " Working a Fine ",
            "post_type": 0,
            "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
            "saved_name": "8.jpg",
            "file_Name": "7.jpg,8.jpg"
        }, {
            "post_id": 2,
            "user_id": 1,
            "description": " Hello hi",
            "post_type": 1,
            "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
            "saved_name": "4.jpg",
            "file_Name": "6.jpg,5.jpg,4.jpg"
        }, {
            "post_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "description": " Hi How are you ",
            "post_type": 0,
            "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
            "saved_name": "1.jpg",
            "file_Name": "3.jpg,2.jpg,1.jpg"
        }]
    }





 #Required OUT PUT:


{
    "status": 200,
    "error": null,
    "res_posts": [{
        "post_id": 3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "description": " Working a Fine ",
        "post_type": 0,
        "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
        "saved_name": "8.jpg",
        "file_Name": ["7.jpg", "8.jpg"]
    }, {
        "post_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "description": " Hello hi",
        "post_type": 1,
        "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
        "saved_name": "4.jpg",
        "file_Name": ["6.jpg","5.jpg","4.jpg"]
    }, {
        "post_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "description": " Hi How are you ",
        "post_type": 0,
        "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
        "saved_name": "1.jpg",
        "file_Name": ["3.jpg","2.jpg","1.jpg"]
    }]
}
 MYSQL OUTPUT : "file_Name": "3.jpg,2.jpg,1.jpg"     
 My Required OUT PUT: "file_Name": ["3.jpg","2.jpg","1.jpg"]

``````````````````````````````

i had a problem with file_Name out put it comes in string format but i want it in array , So please anyone help me in this to get required output .
```````````````````````````````

Comment: Please share query

Comment: There is nothing like a `json string` or a `json array` format. json is a string-based representation of data that has to be parsed if you want to work with it. So either it is json or it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your replay , but i need solution from current output to required output

Answer (score 0):

you can map on the structure.

```js
const outputJson = `{
  "status": 200,
  "error": null,
  "res_posts": [{
      "post_id": 3,
      "user_id": 1,
      "description": " Working a Fine ",
      "post_type": 0,
      "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
      "saved_name": "8.jpg",
      "file_Name": "7.jpg,8.jpg"
  }, {
      "post_id": 2,
      "user_id": 1,
      "description": " Hello hi",
      "post_type": 1,
      "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
      "saved_name": "4.jpg",
      "file_Name": "6.jpg,5.jpg,4.jpg"
  }, {
      "post_id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "description": " Hi How are you ",
      "post_type": 0,
      "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
      "saved_name": "1.jpg",
      "file_Name": "3.jpg,2.jpg,1.jpg"
  }]
}`;

const parsedJson = JSON.parse(outputJson);
parsedJson.res_posts = parsedJson.res_posts.map(item => {
  item.file_Name = item.file_Name.split(',');
  return item;
});

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(parsedJson);
console.log(parsedJson);
```

```html
<pre id="content"></pre>
```